# Is building one large better than building small ~75-100 widgets

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider the case that I have 3 adjacent list view with each list view having a sized widget of some height. Each list view has around 24 child items. I'm trying to scale the widget using `onScaleUpdate` in `GestureDetector`.

onScaleUpdate I want to change the height of each child item of all the 3 listviews.

Is rebuilding all child better or should I rebuild the whole widget?

Comment: Use `ListView.builder`, if items are too heavy separate the context by creating widget

Answer (score 1):

As [@Yeasin Sheikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10157127/yeasin-sheikh) pointed out, using `ListView.builder` is good because it builds only the needed children (the ones inside the screen and just a few ones outside as precaution). And as to actually answering your question, I'm no Flutter expert, but using `ListView.builder` I don't think it makes that much difference, Flutter is intelligent enough to solve this by itself.